# How do you convert PKCS#12 String to Certificate and PrivateKey?

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

I am receiving the following String from a certificate stored in Azure Key Vault. I am using the Secret API in order to retrieve both the certificate and the private key related to this cert.

Initially the certificate was uploaded using a .pfx file to Azure Key vault. Now I need to create a Certificate and a PrivateKey to allow client authentication to a 3rd party system and I am using the given String retrieved from the API, however I am note sure how to get around that in Java.

I took some hints from [this](https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2018/07/03/azure-key-vault-certificates-are-secrets) link in C# however I am pretty certain that this method doesn't work like that in Java. In particular an X509Certificate or a Certificate in general doesn't hold any information about the PrivateKey in Java, unlike C#, and I am not sure how to extract that information from given String in Java.

This works as expected to retrieve the certificate from the String retrieved from the API

```
String secret = azureSecret.getValue();
byte[] certkey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret);
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certkey);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(inputStream);
```

The `azureSecret.getValue()` format is like the following however I am not sure how to get PrivateKey out of the given String

```
MIIKvgIBaaZd6Euf3EYwYdHrIIKYzCC...
```

Answer (score 0):

YES, Java [`X509Certificate` and `Certificate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html) is only the certificate. **Instead use [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html)** which can contain multiple entries each of which is *either* a 'trusted' certificate (for someone else), or a privatekey plus certificate plus other chain cert(s) (if applicable) for yourself, or (not relevant here) a 'secret' (symmetric) key. PKCS12 is supported as one type of KeyStore along with others not relevant here, so after the base64-decoding you already have do something like:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(inputstreamfromvaultvalue, password);
// then
PrivateKey pkey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, password);
// and
Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias); // if you only need the leaf cert
// or
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias); // usually
```

But if you want to do client authentication *in TLS/SSL* (including HTTPS), you give the JSSE KeyManager the whole keystore object not the individual pieces (privatekey and certificates). Similarly to verify the peer in TLS/SSL, you give TrustManager a keystore containing trusted certificates, usually root CAs and often defaulted to a built-in set of public root CAs.